# How to show DateField with AM/PM format in blackberry?

Tags: user-interface, datetime, blackberry, time, datetime-format

I don't know how to show Time in AM/PM format in blackberry using blackberry datefield.Pls give me a idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa");
long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
DateField dateField = new DateField("time:", date, timeFormat);
add(dateField);
```

[alt text http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/7642/timeformat.jpg](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/7642/timeformat.jpg)