# Blackberry Date Field help

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Please tell me how to add a date field to a screen

It will be in the format of     choose from [image] that box will be button in which after sl

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [DateField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/DateField.html) class. See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648677/how-to-show-datefield-with-am-pm-format-in-blackberry).